# Count null and not null values in a column

Tags: mysql, count, null

How to count and retrieve null and not null on same column in MySQL?

#### mytable

```
---------------------------------------------------
id   |    name    |      visited   |   registDate |
---------------------------------------------------
1    |    george  |       NULL     |   2014-04-01 |
---------------------------------------------------
2    |    Thomas  |       NULL     |   2014-04-15 |
---------------------------------------------------
3    |    Wilfred |        1       |   2014-04-24 |
---------------------------------------------------
4    |    paul    |        1       |   2014-04-10 |
---------------------------------------------------
5    |    elina   |       NULL     |   2014-05-03 |
---------------------------------------------------
6    |    angela  |       NULL     |   2014-04-13 |
---------------------------------------------------
7    |    elina   |        1       |   2014-05-18 |
---------------------------------------------------
```

#### Expected result

```
month      register    visited    not visited
---------------------------------------------
05-2014       2           1          1   
---------------------------------------------
04-2014       5           2          3
---------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 14):

Try

```
SELECT 
   DATE_FORMAT(registDate, '%m-%Y') AS month,
   COUNT(name) AS register,
   SUM(!ISNULL(visited)) AS visited,
   SUM(ISNULL(visited)) AS not_visited
FROM mytable
GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(registDate, '%m-%Y');
```

No need to create another column.

Answer (score 3):

The first thing to do is 'add on' a column for the month:

```
select *, date_format(registDate, '%Y-%m') as regist_month
from mytable
```

Then you can get all the counts:

```
select
  regist_month
, count(registDate) as count_registered
, sum(case when visited is not null then 1 else 0 end) as count_visited
, sum(case when visited is null then 1 else 0 end) as count_not_visited
from (
  select *, date_format(registDate, '%Y-%m') as regist_month
  from mytable
) group by regist_month
```

Comment: You can use count instead of sum and shorten the expression a bit: `count(visited)`. count(<column>) will only count not null. If you add another level of nesting count_not_visited can be determined as `count_registered - count_visited`

Answer (score 3):

In order to count all the non null values for a column, say `col1`, you just may use `count(col1) as cnt_col1`. But, to be more obvious, you may use the `sum()` function and the `IS NOT NULL` operator, becoming `sum(col1 IS NOT NULL)`. That's because the `IS NOT NULL` operator returns an int: 1 for true and 0 for false.

In order to count null values you can use the `IS NULL` operator, which returns 1 when the value null. Like before, with the `sum()` operator.

Given that, in order to get the registered, visited and not visited for each month, this is what you can do:

```
SELECT
date_format(registDate, '%m-%Y') as month,
count(registDate) as register,
sum(visited is not null) as visited,
sum(visited is null) as 'not visited'
GROUP BY
date_format(registDate, '%m-%Y')
```

Note that you could output the 'not visited' column with the space, just by quoting, double quoting or using backticks (`).

Another approach to select and group by month would be to concatenate month with year, like this `concat(month(registDate), '-', date(registDate))`. But it's less elegant.

The `case` operator proposed in other responses is perfectly valid, but I think it more adequate for other situations. And it's more verbose.